# Word-based autocomplete for textarea (with or without Mootools)

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, textarea, mootools

I'ld like to have a autocomplete function for a textarea but not for the full contents (text). It should work on every word while you're typing.

I add the letters "aut" here just in the middle of the text and it should offer me "autocomplete" (from a predefined/external list of words).

Does something like this exist?

Due to local regulations, I'm limited to Mootools as framework, jQuery is not allowed but any pure JS is fine.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the [MooTools Forge](http://mootools.net/forge/)? There you'll find plenty of MooTools based solutions.

The one you're looking for is called [Meio.Autocomplete](http://mootools.net/forge/p/meio_autocomplete), but there are [some other ways](http://ajaxdump.com/2010/08/11/10-cool-auto-complete-scripts-using-ajaxjquerymootoolsprototype/) of solving this, too.

Comment: Looks like none of the are working with textarea or for suggesting single words within a text (except FCBKcomplete, but it's not really a text and it's jQuery).

Comment: Sorry, I've somehow overread you wanted to put this into a textarea. Well, for this you only have to tweak the class a little bit so the data you want to autocomplete is only the last word or something like this.